# Making an executable GEM from a script

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I started developing ruby lately and I really like it, But I feel somehow lost. I developed a script that does "whatever" and that scripts requires many gems like **nokogiri** and **colorize**. I now want to deploy the script, so after reading a while I found many people saying that deploying as a gem is the best approach. So my question is simple? Is there any tool that I can use to create a gem of my script file and include all the gem dependencies(nokogiri) in the new gem?

I am using ubuntu!

Thanks alot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Building a gem consists of basically creating a simple directory structure for your script, and a special file known as a gemspec that will list all its dependencies. That gemspec can be used with rubygems to create a gem file (*.gem), which can be installed using rubygems or uploaded to rubygems.org for public consumption.

There are several tools that automate part of this process. A relatively simple one is the Bundler gem, which will both take care of dependencies during development, and make it easy for you to package your gem. [This article](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2011/01/10/using-bundler-for-ruby-gem-development/) contains enough information to get you started with gem development using bundler.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to make a gem is to use the bundler program to build a skeleton:

```
# bundler gem (gem_name)
bundler gem geil_gem
```

This will create a template `gemspec` file and give you the basic structure needed for your gem to have a `setup` command, a `console` and be ready to build into a working gem (both found in the bin folder of your skeleton project). From here you can add a command binary or build out the `gem` as a library using the lib directory or start with tests by adding `rspec` to the `gemspec` and creating a test folder.